# ASP.NET Core MVC model binding does not work with TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, redirecttoaction, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an `<input type="hidden" id="pipo" name="pipo" value />` in the `layout.cshtml`.

In a method of my controller, I set `TempData["pipo"] = "xyz";` and then `return RedirectToAction(nameof(aView));`.

When `aView` is rendered, the input "pipo" has "xyz" as value.

But when in another method, I set `TempData["pipo"] = "xyz"` but in place of a `return RedirectionToAction` I have a `return View("aView")`, the pipo input does not have a value.

I tried making a

```
return RedirectToAction("aView")
```

in place of

```
return View("aView")
```

in that case the input have a value "xyz". Maybe I lost something in the way that values from `TempData` goes to an `<input>` or maybe there is something that `RedirectToAction` does that `View()` does not.

Temporarily, I'm doing 2 loads, with a `RedirectToAction` when I need it, but there should be a way to not doing that.

Comment: Temp data can be used to set a property. But how are you expecting that value to set the `<input value="">`? You'd need to use a tag helper or some explicit c# code somewhere...

Comment: Actually, Model Binding do exactly that work, but only if I use RedirectToAction, not when I use a View directly.
May be, in the process of RedirectToAction, Model Binding take  TempData like a Source Binding, but when use View does not.

Answer (score 0):

Temp data can be used to set a property. But how are you expecting that value to set the  ?
send your input value to your controller method values and then from that value assign it your tempdata variable.

Like:

```
public ActionResult BatchPapers(string pipo)
{
  if(pipo != null)
      {
     TempData["pipo"] = pipo; 
      }
  else{
     TempData["pipo"] = "xyz" 
      }
}
```

Comment: I don't spect that, I just want that model binding work in the same way with a RedirectToAction than with a View(), I know that with the former Crete a new request, but in the context of model binding, may be can work in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to retrive your scenario:

```
        public IActionResult aView()
        {
            TempData["pipo"] = "xyz";

            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Method1()
        {
            return View("aView");
        }

        public IActionResult Method2()
        {
            
            return RedirectToAction("aView");
        }
```

```
<input id="pipo" name="pipo" value=@TempData["pipo"] />
```

Go Method1 won't change value to xyz. But Method2 could do the change.
This is because `return view("aView")` won't make a new request, it just go directly to the `aView.cshtml`. 
But `return RedirectToAction("aView")` will make a new request to aview method first, so it changed the value.
[Difference Between return View(), return Redirect(), return RedirectToAction()](https://devbloggies.blogspot.com/2019/07/difference-between-return-view-return-redirect-return-redirecttoaction-and-redirecttoroute-in-mvc.html)

Comment: The value of TempData does not change, if I use View, the Input is null, but if I use RedirectToAction, the input has the value from TempData.
The question is Why, I spect that model binding work in the same way with  or without a new request,  I spect that model binding make your magic some time between the call to a view and the resulting rendered page...

Comment: @ArielRodriguez can you post more code? Maybe i misunderstand. You can make View also work the same by adding TempData["pipo"] = "xyz"; in mehtod1 .

Comment: Hi Jerry, if the input in the View does not have a value, with redirectoToAction, the input has a xyz value, but when you use View the input value doesn't.
I know that if I set the value to template, all work fine, but the question is, why work with redirectToAction and not with a View, when the model binding is the same...

Comment: @ArielRodriguez Maybe i misunderstand, but the reason or difference is just 'view' go to page directly ingnoring the method. 'RedirectToAction' go to method first.